# Consumir JSON en jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

deseo saber como consumir JSON atraves de jQuery.

```
[{"Id":3,"dep_Id":2,"departamento":{"Id":2,"Departamento":"Tecnolog\u00eda","Descripcion":"casita","created_at":"2019-12-16 05:48:03","updated_at":"2019-12-19 23:34:09"}}]
```

Esto lo hago por medio de Ajax jQuery pero no se como extraerlos para presentarlo a la vista.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu respuesta es un array de objetos con un solo elemento.  Para accesarlo puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
var response = [{"Id":3,"dep_Id":2,"departamento":{"Id":2,"Departamento":"Tecnolog\u00eda","Descripcion":"casita","created_at":"2019-12-16 05:48:03","updated_at":"2019-12-19 23:34:09"}}];

console.log(response[0].Id);
console.log(response[0].departamento);
```

Comment: Extelente, me soluciono el problemita rapidito, gracias amigo...